# How to return to a particular part of a loop after continue?

Tags: python-2.7, try-catch, continue

I am learning to use classes. I have built exceptions into one of my defined methods, setBirthday. It ensures that the inputs are appropriate for a true birthday output. This section of code is not working as I would like it.

```
    def setBirthday(you):
    while True:
        #get numeric birth month
        try:
            m = int(raw_input("What is your birth month?"))
        except ValueError:
            print "Enter an integer, please try again."
            continue
        if m <= 0:
            print "Enter a number between 1-12, please try again."
            continue
        elif m >= 13:
            print "Enter a number between 1-12, please try again."
            continue
      #get birth date
        try:
            d = int(raw_input("What day were you born that month?"))
        except ValueError:
            print "Enter an integer, please try again."
            continue        
        if d <= 0:
            print "Enter a number between 1-31, please try again."
            continue
        elif d >= 32:
            print "Enter a number between 1-31, please try again."
            continue
        #get birth year
        try:
            y = int(raw_input("What year were you born?"))
        except ValueError:
            print "Enter an integer, please try again."
            continue        
        if y <= 0:
            print "Enter a number greater than zero, please try again."
            continue
        else:
            break
    you.bday = datetime(y, m, d)
    age = str(m) + "/" + str(d) + "/" + str(y)
    print "Your birthday is " + (age)
```

As it runs now if someone inputs a undesirable input for the day of the month (d) or the year of birth (y), 'continue' restarts the whole loop again: asking for birth month, date, year. I would like to have it continue at the point where it went awry (date or year) rather ask the user again for the previous good inputs to get to that point. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would split it to three different loops, and just exit them with `break` when I get valid input.

Comment: when I add "else" "break" after each it asks over and over again for the month doesn't move on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while True:
    #get numeric birth month
    try:
        m = int(raw_input("What is your birth month?"))
    except ValueError:
        print "Enter an integer, please try again."
        continue
    if m <= 0 or m >= 13:
        print "Enter a number between 1-12, please try again."
    else:
        break
```

Then the same loop for day and the third one for year.